# How to move a WCF service layer from Azure to on-premises

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, deployment, publishing

Due to some (insane) limitation at my customer, I built up a WCF layer using Azure, just as a proof of concept. Now, what is a smooth way to re-deploy it to their on-premises server? Is there such a way?

I understand that the publishing of my service to the cloud is a nice luxury that can't be performed as easily when deploying on-premises.   :(

Because of some (equivalently insane) limitations, I'm not able to connect my computer (with the IDE and source code) to the internal net of the customer. I **might** be able to get an IDE installed on their computer, though. Is moving the source code files and recompiling the only option?

In a perfect world, I'd like to copy the entire project to the customer's computer and just change some settings in a deployment file (or whatever thing stores that information). Is it possible?

Comment: What Azure features are you using? Is it just a WCF Web Service?

Comment: Anyway I would consider to install the Web Deploy Tool. Then you should be able to deploy your "package" remotely.

Comment: @VladimirGondarev Thanks for the reply. The problems is (the said insanity related) that I'm not allowed to install anything on their computers and mine is not being let into the trusted network. I'll need to find a way to deploy from IDE (inside their net) to another server (also inside their net) but **without** any additional software. The vanilla VS12 is all I've got.

Comment: Well, what about the deploying the solution to the local temp folder by using the Deploy Wizard from Visual Studio and then simply create by hands a new application on server side and copy all files there.

Comment: @VladimirGondarev Could work. I'll give it a try tomorrow if I'll get the time (a new customer asked me to check out something). Why don't you put it as a reply and if it works out I'll mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Well, what about the deploying the solution to the local temp folder by using the Deploy Wizard from Visual Studio and then simply create by hands a new application on server side and copy all files there.

Comment: Good suggestions. The problem is that due to the hands-on installation, I need to configure all the other stuff and this far, as described [in this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786507/cant-access-wcf-services-after-deployment?noredirect=1#comment25948302_17786507), I can only serve static HTML pages. I can't get the services to work. If you can help with that, I'll be putting a bounty as soon as StockOverflow allows me to.