# Can't access SVC files in WCF services after deployment

Tags: wcf, deployment, web-deployment

I'm crying blood at the moment. **What more can I do to trouble-shoot and analyse the problem?**

I've deployed my WCF service layer but can't access it. In the same physical directory I that the SVC files are uploaded to, I also placed a static HTML file. The first line gets me that file, while the second complains about the resource being removed, renamed, unavailable etc.

```
http://MyServerName/Services/ping.html  
http://MyServerName/Services/MyService.svc
```

When I deployed the service layer to Azure, I got a WSDL file when accessing it. I'm pretty sure that I'm forgetting some setting on the server but I need a hint on what to look for.

The files are there so the publish process works. The same problem occurs if I try to access the services directly on the server using *localhost*. Suggestions are welcome.

**EDIT**

I ran *aspnet_regiis.exe -iru* as suggested [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751792.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx). I also went through all the settings I could find and I've made sure that WAS is on and that .NET Framework is checked.

I followed [this guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/blambert/archive/2009/02/13/enable-iis.aspx) too, in order to make sure that I haven't overlooked anything. According to it, I didn't - everything was already set up as suggested.

Two system services are stopped (ASP.NET State Service and Web Management Service) but as far I can see, they aren't the problem.

Apparently, the handlers seem to be configured properly as well as the screenshot illustrates. The error message is also included.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with Azure, but I usually encountered a similar error for .svc files when hosting WCF services on IIS on new servers, that hadn't added handler mappings for .svc files. I think you should double check that your hosting environment is able to handle .svc files.

Comment: @CoralDoe Sure, mate. But how?! (Also, please see my edit. I forgot to mention some stuff.)

Comment: This is how you can find installed handlers:http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_2TqL1T92L48/S-Ldg1jrCVI/AAAAAAAAAA8/49TQbjLgXcw/s1600/Handler_Mappings_No_SVC.png

Comment: I would say that something wrong with handlers for svc extension on IIS side. Check available .svc handlers. Maybe there are some other handlers for .svc extension... also what .Net runtime version is selected in App properties?

Comment: @VladimirGondarev I checked the handlers (forgot about them before, so the advice itself is rock solid, thanks) but as far I can see they're configured as supposed to (for the whole site). And the .NET I'm targetting is the highlighted one - 4.0. I created my own application pool but made sure that it targets the correct framework, as well. See the addition to my question - maybe you can spot something I'm missing.

Comment: Could you also post a message/screenshot of a error that you have when you try to access the svc file.

Comment: @VladimirGondarev Sure thing, mate. It's just the usual 404, though. But for completeness' sake, I'll do that. Back in a jiff (takes a few minutes to move files around between computers).

Comment: well, it's time to show the web.config file... :) if there is no sensitive information. what binding is being used for WCF Web Service?

Comment: @VladimirGondarev Put your comments as a reply so I can check it as an answer so you'll get some reputation. I found the problem finally, so you can put that in the reply too. IIS had automagically changed the version to 2.0 **and** the installation of 4.5 had somehow failed (without the error message). I reinstalled 4.5 and changed the IIS (server-wide) to 4.0 and then it worked. Weird poo...

Comment: I am glad that you resolved the issue. :) If you hadn't resolved the issue, we would have had to setup Remote Desktop Connection. Just kidding ...

Comment: @VladimirGondarev Post a reply so I can mark it as an answer, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to check:

1. Handlers for svc extension on IIS side.
2. .Net runtime version for the app pool.